# iOS7, ability to search web via Spotlight search

Tags: spotlight, ios, search

Prior to iOS7, if someone wanted to search the web, generally the easiest way to do so was by entering your query into the spotlight, and then just clicking 'Search Safari/Wikipedia'. After upgrading to iOS7, the option to search the web is no longer there, so opening Safari/Chrome/etc., is now required, which actually adds a significant amount of time to each search you do if you use this often.

**Did iOS7 completely revoke the ability to do this? Is there any way to get it back?**

[image]

Comment: Yes it's gone, and no there's no way to get it back. Not sure I buy that it's much slower though, since in the old method you had to go to the home screen, page all the way the left, enter your query, wait for the options to search the web to come up, tap on it, wait for the browser to load...

Comment: @tubedogg, ok. Yeah, I mean it's just hard to believe that they would make the spotlight so much more simple to access no matter where you are, but then drop one of the most powerful functions within it.

Comment: It is slower. Swiping your finger and starting to type is much faster than opening Safari, waiting for it to load, clicking the box so the search bar will show, deleting whatever is currently in that box, and then beginning to type takes much longer. Not including the web in spotlight search is just stupid.